# Missing Template Argument with Vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to make a class that will create a vector and use a bubble sort on it. Everything compiles just fine except when I attempt to create a BubbleStorage class called bubble.

The compiler gives me an error "missing template argument before bubble", "expected ; before bubble".

This code is not finished; however, as I am still in the process of making the bubble sort functions. I just want to take care of this before moving on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class BubbleStorage
{
public:
    BubbleStorage();
    ~BubbleStorage();
    vector<T>MyVector;

    void add_data(int size)
    {
        srand (time(NULL));

        for (T i = 0; i <= size; i++)
            random = rand() % 100;
        MyVector.push_back(random);
    }

    void display_data()
    {
        cout<<"The Vector Contains the Following Numbers"<<endl;
        for (vector<int>::iterator i = MyVector.begin(); i != MyVector.end(); ++i)
            cout<<' '<< *i;
    }

    void max()
    {

    }

    void min()
    {

    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    int size = rand() % 50 + 25;
    BubbleStorage bubble;

    bubble.add_data(size);
    bubble.display_data();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BubbleStorage is a templated class and needs a template argument.

try

```
BubbleStorage<int> bubble;
```

Also given this template argument, make sure in your class functions you don't assume an "int" or "double" or even "MyClass" use T, the template parameter. So if you want an iterator for the vector its

```
vector<T>::iterator //or
vector<T>::const_iterator
```

In `add_data` you shouldn't assume that `T` is int convertable. You should have an external function to grab random `T`s. Given these issues, make sure that you actually need `BubbleStorage` to be templated. Or have `add_data` take a `T` instead of a size of the vector.

Comment: Thank you! I decided against using the template and now it's working just fine!